# Is it possible to filter over nested objects on stream-chat?

Tags: getstream-io, getstream-chat

stream-chat v6.7.3

When I connect a user besides id, name, and image, I'm adding my own properties as an object, like this:

```
await client.connectUser({
            id: 'jose',
            name: 'pepe',
            image:'https://i.imgur.com/YEGTFwf.jpeg',
            myObject:{
                'id':1,
                'categoria':'writer'
            }
        },
        client.devToken('jose'));
```

but then when I try to query the user it simply returns an empty array, I'm trying like this:

```
await client.queryUsers({"myObject.categoria":"writer"});
```

I have tried over id, or other properties inside the user object and the filter works like a charm, so I'm wondering if this is the right way to do the query. Or if is it possible to query over an inside object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to stream support, "Currently the API can't filter over nested objects like this, only values in the top level."

Answer (score 1):

Only top level is supported. Objects needs flattening. Arrays have more tools `$contains` and `$in`.

For example:

Let's say `data` is `colors: ['yellow', 'black']`

then `colors: {$contains: ['yellow', 'white']}` can find it.